# How to call a matlab function specifying explicitly every argument

Tags: function, matlab, variadic-functions

I am wondering if i can create (and call) a function where i can specify the arguments explicitly, like this:

```
myFun(arg1 = 1, arg3 = "test_string")
```

where

```
function = myFun(arg1,arg2,arg3)

            if exist(arg1,'var')
                %do something
            end
            if exist(arg2,'var')
                %do something
            end
            if exist(arg1,'var')
                %do something
            end

%do something
end
```

I want to create a class constructor that initialized the class attributes if they are provided in the constructor call.

Comment: Not an answer but some related readings: [Name=Value in Function Calls](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/namevalue-in-function-calls.html) is supported since R2021a (with a few caveat). And obviously [Validate Name-Value Arguments](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/validate-name-value-arguments.html)

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the `arguments` function [mathworks doc](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arguments.html). Personally I use this for optional arguments, but you could also use it for your use-case.

```
function myRectangle(options)
arguments
   options.Height (1,1) {mustBeNumeric} = 1
   options.Width (1,1) {mustBeNumeric} = 4
end

% Function code
width = options.Width;
height = options.Height;

area = width * height;

display("rectangle " + width + "x" + height + " has an area of: " + area)
end
```

Results in

```
myRectangle("Width", 3, "Height", 2)
    "rectangle 3x2 has an area of: 6"
myRectangle("Height", 2, "Width", 3)
    "rectangle 3x2 has an area of: 6"
```

Comment: i added an edit that includes checks to see if the argumetns where passed by the user. Thanks